# How do I download the email I just sent using Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I am using GraphAPI for sending email.  I have a situation where I need to Save a copy of the email sent. I can retrieve the Messages using graph api. How do I identify the email I just sent? When I use the SendEmail endpoint of the Graph api, I get a 200 OK response. How do I identify the email I just sent so I can download that email?

I have tried a number of solutions, adding custom Identifiers and filtering it but none of them worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The easiest would probably be to send the email to yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but this approach seems it would work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id#immutable-id-with-sending-mail.

1. Create the message as a draft with `Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"` header
2. Save the returned id
3. Send the draft

Note that email sending is asynchronous so you might not be able to download the sent email right away. It could take some time to be available.

Comment: I tried putting Prefer-IdType in the request header, it creates a message, I get an id and then after sending the message with that Id, it gets sent as well but when I search for a message with that Id, it does not exists!

Comment: Have you checked if it exists but the id changed? With the "ImmutableId" it shouldn't in most cases but I did have issues with calendar events with that in the past :\